# xamarin-Android release mode fail (Debug work)

Tags: android, xamarin.android

not        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

```
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);


        string link = "http://www.google.com";
        HttpWebRequest iNetRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);

        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)iNetRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader _str2 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(936));
        string html = _str2.ReadToEnd();
        Toast.MakeText(this, html.Substring(0, 200), ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }

}
```

The above simple code will work with debug mode but not with release mode. Even though I have already add internet permission into AndroidManifest.xml. Anybody has any ideal? Best regards.
   [AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia4ML.png)

Comment: What about it "doesn't work"?

Comment: With Debug mode, it work normally, get HTML and show it. With release mode the app crashed from the beginning.  I guest that the app can not connect to internet and get HTML but I have already add internet permission to AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: When it crashes do you not get details of the crash? You should be able to get a stack trace from the crash.

Comment: Just found the reason.It`s seen that Encoding.GetEncoding(936) is the reason. I changed to GetEncoding("utf-8") then the problem will be solved. But my project need to get HTML from some chinese website so I need encode(936). any ideal?

Comment: I have use Portable.Text.Encoding instead of System.Text.Encoding. And all the problem are solved. Thanks u. regards.